# jquery different effects while showing the hidden elements

Tags: jquery

I want to give different transition effects like :

```
 $(div).show("fadeIn")  $(div).show("shake") $(div).show("fold") etc
```

How can i do this in jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fadeIn - http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

`$("div").fadeIn("slow");`

---

For shake - http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Shake

```
$("div").click(function () {
  $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 300);
});
```

---

For fold - http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Fold

```
$("div").click(function () {
  $(this).hide("fold", {}, 1000);
});
```

---

You can check all the default effects at: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible transition using JQueryUI lib : http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Else, you can use standard JQuery animations like

```
$(selector).fadeIn(300) /*300 is the duration in miliseconds*/
$(selector).slideUp(300)
...
```

Have a nice day